# Why is Knockout populating a column for all rows with the same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

Here's a fiddle with a few things omitted: http://jsfiddle.net/YwTBk/

Essentially what is needed to get the image below is simply editing the first row. For some reason, Knockout is filling all of the rows under that column with the same value. It happens for the `amount`, `nrAmount`, and of course the computed `total` column. None of the other columns have this problem.

It is interesting to note that changing the binding from `amount` to `$data.amount` has the effect of making the computed column `nrAmount` not work anymore but it doesn't cause all of the rows to get populated.

[image: A column getting filled down with the same value]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The binding syntax looks fine to me. The problem seems to be somewhere else. Since your fiddle is incomplete, it could be in the missing components. Could be another event, or subscription causing the update?

Comment: @adaptive The only things I really omitted were populating the categories and departments observable arrays. I also have that `<tbody>` inside a `<table>` with a `<thead>` definition. All of the JavaScript code and bindings in HTML regarding the word "amount" were in that fiddle. I have been confused on this one for quite a while. I'll write a test case for it I guess.

Comment: Your fiddle is not working at all, you did not even include knockout.

Comment: There is at least one major issue: You are always beginning function definitions with `self = this;`. If you do not use `var self = this;`, this variable `self` will be global and therefore overwritten by the next call to any of these functions.

Comment: @Niko That was it pretty much. It was then a matter of just adjusting the bindings. This is what I get for not understanding the code examples to their entirety! If you want to copy/paste that as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle that 'works', I guess - http://jsfiddle.net/YwTBk/2/.  Your description of the problem doesn't match the fiddle you referenced, so it's hard to say for sure.

The bigger problems I fixed were as follows:

1. As Niko mentioned, you need `var self = this;` at the top of your viewmodels.
2. I moved addBlankRecord inside your viewmodel so that the `self` reference in the addBlankRecord method will work.
3. I updated the populateBlankRecords method so that it references the addBlankRecord on your ViewModel
4. For your bindings, I updated the bindings for categories and removeRecord to $parent.categories and $parent.removeRecord because neither of those are found in the Record viewmodel.

There were also several smaller issues that I'm guessing were a result of things being stripped out of your code.  Some of these were referenced by other comments.

- the removeRecord, GetDepartments, and GetCategories methods did not exist
- there was no table HTML tag
- there were no references to jQuery or KnockoutJS

Does this fix your problem?  If not, it would be very helpful if you could provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: These are exactly the changes I made. Thanks for summarizing it into an answer. You get the tick. :)